# C - How print an integer with system call?

Tags: c, printing, int, system-calls

For my project I must print an integer value without using function library (ex. `itoa`, `sprintf`, `printf`, fprintf, `fwrite` etc...), but I can use only system call `write()`

Comment: Please always show us your effort when asking a question. What have you tried to prepare the decimal represenation and print it?

Comment: Nit picking but `write()` is still a library function call and not a system call.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Now that's *really* nitpicking!  By that definition there are no system calls in C; they're available only to assembly-language programmers.

Comment: @SteveSummit I agree. Maybe `sys_call` can be thought differently. But yes, I was taking it too literally.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print an integer number without using library function like `printf`, `fwrite`. You can use `write()` system call. Open manual page of `write`. It says

> write() writes up to count bytes from the buffer starting at buf to
>   the file referred to by the file descriptor fd.
>
> `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_tcount);`

For e.g

```
int num = 1234;
write(STDOUT_FILENO,&num,sizeof(num));
```

Or

```
write(1,&num,sizeof(num)); /* stdout --> 1  */
```

Above `write()` system call will write `num` into `stdout` stream.

**Edit :-** If your input is `integer` & your want to convert it into string & print it, but don't want to use library function like `itoa()` or `sprintf()` & `printf()`. For that you need to implement user define `sprintf()` & then use `write()`.

```
int main(void) {
        int  num = 1234; 
        /* its an integer, you need to convert the given integer into
        string first, but you can't use sprintf()
        so impliment your own look like sprintf() */

        /*let say you have implimented itoa() or sprintf()
        and new_arr containg string 1234 i,e "1234"*/

        /* now write new_arr into stdout by calling write() system call */  
        write(1,new_arr,strlen(new_arr)+1);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the assignment was to print the number, say, 100 as the 3-character string `100`, not as the binary bytes `0x00 0x64` or some such.

Comment: I misunderstood earlier. Thanks @SteveSummit I modified my answer.

Comment: I have undone my downvote.  I would note, though, that (a) you've sort of helped user Marco cheat, by doing his homework for him, and (b) the answer boils down to writing the `itoa` function, which is itself a standard exercise, and which can be written considerably more straightforwardly.  (You might want to do a web search to see some.)

Comment: I understood @SteveSummit I'll be careful now onwards.